# Windows 10 Magic SysRq-like command

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

So I've got a MacBook Pro in a HengeDock, which prohibits access to the physical power button on the machine. I also use a few Thunderbolt devices to use the computer as a full desktop, and Windows doesn't support hot-plugging of Thunderbolt devices, so rebooting when it hangs normally goes something like

1. Pull MBP out of dock
2. Slam down device (Hold power button and wait until machine is off)
3. Reboot while holding option key, reboot into OS X
4. Put computer back into dock
5. Select Windows as startup disk in OS X
6. Reboot machine
7. Windows boots and is happy.

Now, that's a lot of steps - it usually takes me about 4 minutes to recover from a full hang, while being an entirely interactive process. However, if I reboot Windows straight away, no issues arise (i.e. start-power-restart, or even a full bluescreen crash - no problem.)

I know that the Linux kernel supports the "magic SysRq key" - which I have used and works just fine for this situation.

Is there a way that I could essentially do the SysRq + R/E/I/S/U/B type command on Windows? Or would it not work on a hung system?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've been looking for exactly that for some time now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only emergency hotkey in Windows is <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> (repeat 2×) to manually initiate a crash/bluescreen – which then often results in an automatic reboot. See this article:

- [Forcing a System Crash from the Keyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545499(v=vs.85).aspx)

Short summary on how to activate it (requires a reboot):

```
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Parameters /v CrashOnCtrlScroll /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\kbdhid\Parameters /v CrashOnCtrlScroll /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Comment: Do you know if this is kernel-level? I would assume it is because as far as I know only a kernel fault can blue screen a system.

Comment: It's done in the keyboard drivers (i8042prt for PS/2 and kbdhid for USB keyboards). As the documentation link says, the drivers use the [KeBugCheck()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551948(v=vs.85).aspx) function for that.

Comment: very interesting. sub-optimal, but interesting. Thanks!